# stuck with a malfunctioning while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm stuck with this problem in home  work for a long time now, would appreciate your professional help.
I need to simulate filling up rockets destined for a "mission to Mars" with all kinds of items arranged already in an array list. Maximum weight of each rocket including cargo is a given (18,000 Kg), as well as rocket net weight (10,000 Kg) and each item's weight (Item object includes fields "weight" and "itemType", such as "building material", "water", etc,.)

Instructions are to fill each rocket *until it's fully loaded* and only then create another one. It seems that my fellow students ignored this instruction so their code cannot help.

Sorting the array in ascending / descending order according to weight does not solve the problem.

My problem is that although I have used while loops all over, rockets refuse to fill up despite still having space left that can be filled with an item still left on the list. Loop won't skip the next 2-3 items (the most I managed to get is skipping one item) and find the one item that can still be loaded.

Bellow is also the list of items.

```
public ArrayList<U1> loadU1(ArrayList<Item> items) {

    ArrayList<U1> fleetU1 = new ArrayList();

    int i = 0;

    Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

        U1 rocketU1 = new U1(); // create new rocket with zero cargo

         while (rocketU1.canCarry(items.get(i))) { // "canCarry" checks if item's weight fits in:

/* public final boolean canCarry(Item cargo){
        if(currentRocketWeight + cargo.weight <= maxRocketWeight){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false; }} */


 rocketU1.carry(items.get(i));

// "carry" updates rocket total weight - no more than 18000 Kg including rocket net weight 10000 Kg, i.e. max cargo weight is 8000 Kg:

/* public final int carry(Item cargo){
           currentRocketWeight += cargo.weight;
           return currentRocketWeight;}
      */
           items.remove(i); // remove loaded item from list

          }

        fleetU1.add(rocketU1); // add rocket to fleet
    }

    return fleetU1;
}

/*arraylist "items" - "phase-1.txt":

building tools=2000
building tools=2000
building tools=2000
building tools=5000
building tools=5000
building tools=2000
building tools=1000
building tools=5000
building tools=6000
shelter equipment=5000
construction equipment=5000
plants=1000
steel=8000
books=1000
water=5000*/

public ArrayList<Item> loadItems(int phaseNum) {

try {
        switch (phaseNum) {
            case 1:
                out.println("Loading phase 1:");
                fileName = "phase-1.txt";
                break;
            case 2:
                out.println("Loading phase 2:");
                fileName = "phase-2.txt";
                break;
            default:
            out.println("argument must be 1 or 2");
        }

        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();

            String[] list = lineFromFile.split("=");
            Item item = new Item(); //(list[0], );
            item.itemType = list[0];
            item.weight = Integer.parseInt(list[1]);

            itemList.add(item); // create ArrayList of items
        }

        scanner.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return itemList;
```

}

Comment: Are u sure u are using the iterator correctly? iterator.hasNext() will always be true if you don't invoke iterator.next(). And you modify the backing collection with remove which will result in a ConcurrentModificationException. And what is that index for? Your code doesn't make any sense at all since u are mixing up loop concepts. Please have a look at [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

Comment: @Meini I'm not sure of anything. This is my first iterator ever, after failing with the whiles and ifs.. index i is used to retrieve weight of each item in the list and previously had been incremented but that did not help either. I've been trying so many ways to tackle this problem so no wonder this looks a mess. Plus I'm really a beginner, learning on my own, a lot from this website as well. Thanks for your feedback...

Comment: Do you *need* to use iterators? Using an enhanced for loop makes things a lot easier to write and read: `for (Item item : items) { /* do stuff with current item, or break to exit */ }`

Comment: @tucuxi, no, not necessarily. tried it out of despair... They actually say in the course the best way to loop through an ArrayList is through a "for" loop. Will give your enhanced one a try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have one method to fill a rocket and then call that method in a loop while there is still cargo left to load. To make this work without recursive calls I have changed the array of rockets, `fleet', to be a class member

```
private List<Item> loadRocket(List<Item> items) {        
    Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator();
    List<Item> loaded = new ArrayList<>();
    U1 rocketU1 = new U1();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Item item = iterator.next();
        if (rocketU1.canCarry(item)) {
            rocketU1.carry(item);
            loaded.add(item);
        } 
    }
    items.removeAll(loaded);
    fleetU1.add(rocketU1);
    return items;
}
```

And then call it in a loop

```
while (!items.isEmpty()) {
    items = loadRocket(items);
}
```

If you don't want to have the ´fleet`as a class member you could move the creation of the rocket and adding to the`fleet`list to outside of ´loadRocket` and instead send it as a parameter.

```
while (!items.isEmpty()) {
    U1 rocket = new U1();
    items = loadRocket(rocket, items);
    fleet.add(rocket);
}
```

Comment: This exactly what we have in question `currentRocketWeight < maxRocketWeight` most probably checked in `canCary`. BTW problem is in not updating `i`.

Comment: @talex, canCarry is different. I did notice the double while loops and how the iterator is used after posting. Need to look into that.

Comment: This looks promising, will try it out after lunch and let you know how it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: You rock :-)  it works! (I know it was a long lunch break). I did it a bit differently because requirement was to use one "loadU1" method that will return the list of fully loaded rockets:

Comment: List<Rocket> loadU1(List<Item> items) {
Collections.sort(items, new SortLists()); // sorting list per weight in descending order
while (!items.isEmpty()) {
  Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator();
  List<Item> loaded = new ArrayList<>();
  U1 rocketU1 = new U1();

      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
           Item item = iterator.next();
                if (rocketU1.canCarry(item)) {
                    rocketU1.carry(item);
                    loaded.add(item);
                     }}
      items.removeAll(loaded);
      fleetU1.add(rocketU1); 
        } return fleetU1; }

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the items per rocket.

```
// create a copy of the items so we can remove without harm to the caller
List<Items> ourList = new ArrayList<>(items);
// you should probably sort the list by weight, descending order

while (!ourList.isEmpty()) {
    // we need a rocket.
    U1 rocket = new U1();
    // go through all the items and load if item fits
    Iterator<Item> iterator = ourList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        // the next() call that's mentioned in the comment
        Item item = iterator.next();
        if (rocket.canCarry(item)) {
            rocket.carry(item);
            // you need to remove from the iterator itself, not from the list
            // or you will get an exception because that makes the iterator invalid
            // it will remove from the underlying list as well though
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
    fleet.add(rocket);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, daniu. I appreciate your help. Problem with this code is I encounter for the first time what Meini had warned about: ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: @tucuxi [Yes, you can modify a list while iterating](https://ideone.com/AhrD64). As I wrote in the comment in the answer, you do need to call `remove()` of the iterator, not the underlying collection.

Comment: @Meravi I don't know what your issue is, [runs fine for me](https://ideone.com/Ko4IAt).

Comment: @daniu oops - You are right about iteration and calls to remove(), and I would like to reverse my vote, but it seems I have to wait to do so (or until you edit the question).

Answer (score 0):

So here what I would do:

For each item, I would try to place it in a rocket already in the fleet; if not possible, I would add a new rocket to the fleet. If the item cannot fit even in an empty rocket, it is kept in the input list, otherwise, it is removed:

```
public List<U1> loadU1(List<Item> items) {
    List<U1> fleetU1 = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Item item = iterator.next();
        U1 rocketU1 = null;
        for (U1 u1: fleetU1) {
            if (u1.canCarry(item)) {
                rocketU1 = u1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (rocketU1 == null) {
            rocketU1 = new U1();
            if (!rocketU1.canCarry(item)) {
                // the item is too heavy
                continue;
            }
            fleetU1.add(rocketU1);
        }
        rocketU1.carry(item);
        iterator.remove();
    }
    return fleetU1;
}
```

Comment: Note that the solution obtained is not necessarily optimal: it depends on the order of the items in the list.

Comment: Also, if the `continue` is reached, this will result in an endless loop since the item is never removed from the list being iterated.

Comment: @daniu you're wrong about that: it's `iterator.next()` that advances the iterator.

Comment: you're right, the items list won't be empty in the end but I guess that's not really an issue for the problem at hand.

Comment: @daniu at the end, the list will contain the items that are too heavy to fit in a rocket. Makes sense.

Comment: Thank you Maurice. Before posting I had actually reached the point where all items are loaded (none is too heavy, at worst one item fills up a rocket). Problem is for some reason some rockets did not fill up and new ones were already created although items that could be loaded on half empty or nearly full rockets were still on the list. I'm looking for optimal loading, where order of items in the list does not make any difference. (There are actually two lists, one for U1 rockets and one for U2 rockets. The second one fills up easily but once you test changing order of items it freaks out.)

Comment: @Meravi as I said, this algorithm produces one solution, not necessarily the optimal solution. Finding the optimal solution is more complicated.

Comment: @Meravi note that you could obtain a better solution by sorting the items by weight, heaviest first; still not necessarily optimal though.

Comment: @Meravi you could try this algorithm: http://www.or.deis.unibo.it/kp/Chapter8.pdf

Comment: @daniu ALL items must be loaded.

Comment: @Meravi If you have an item with 10k weight, it won't be able to load onto a rocket with your specification. In this solution, it will be left in the list; in my solution, it will throw an exception. Do note that this solution has a few more iterations than necessary (you will iterate through already filled rockets again for each following item).

Comment: True regarding sorting in descending order, and indeed I added a method as you can see in my comment to Joackim.